# IFTTT endpoint test gives me following error at setup

Tags: ifttt

IFTTT endpoint test gives me following error at setup what does this really mean ?

'data' property exists and is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question , I was missing Response body format later I come to know after going thru documentation at https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/api_reference

Response body format
Provide response bodies as JSON objects. Success responses have a top-level wrapper object called data.

Raw body on success
{
  "data": {
    // The value of `data` varies, but is typically
    // either an object or array
    ...
  }
}